# To show the aggregate of duplicated values that another corresponding attribute in another table is NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

Not sure if I have described the context clearly in the title
but the situation is given two tables

```
A|B 
1|1 
1|2 
2|3 
2|4 
3|5 
4|6
5|7 
5|8 

B|C
1|NULL
2|1
3|NULL
4|NULL
5|NULL
6|2
7|3
8|4
```

the condition of output is the value of A should appear more than 1 time,
while the corresponding B values are not both NULL in C (at least 1 value of C from B is not NULL)

**what matches the conditions of the above table by A should be 1 and 5
the expected output of the count of duplicated A is 2**

Comment: Please format the question clearly to show the two tables in separate code blocks. Also, please add expected output based on the given sample data in formatted text.

Comment: @JkL according to your logic 1,2,5 will come to output not only 1 and 5

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin not at all. values for 2 has `null` in column C.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya 2|1  not found null for 2 in column c

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin please check the data (and may be re-read the question again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should help.

```
select t.a,count(t.a),count(t2.c)
 from t
 join t2
   on t.b=t2.b
group by t.a
having count(t.a)>1
   and count(t2.c)>=1
```

Here i join the table t and t2 on the column b
after that i check how many records have col-a in table t are >1 and also how many in col c in t2 are> 1.

Just FYI,count(null) would be zero) so any non-null value in t2.c will have count(t2.c)>=1

Full demo

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6d56b0ed8bafe09786342a6bfb58b8d2

Comment: DB fiddle for MySQL: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/36yk27AdB9cW34KDgPpzrQ/0

Comment: Appreciated. The outputs are desired but how could I show the aggregate count of the resulted rows. Like if 1 2 3 4 5 6 are the rows and I would like to only have the aggregation of 6.

Comment: Include a count(*) over(partition by 1) in the query as follows. This works in SQL Server and not in MySQL my bad..

Comment: Add an inline query to it as follows.https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/36yk27AdB9cW34KDgPpzrQ/1

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to sql but may you explain how such inline query would do the job?

Comment: Think of the inline query as a view. We are interested in counting how many rows are returned by the view output, and so select count(*) from (<inline_view>) gets you the result

Answer (score 0):

you can try by using exists

```
select t1.A,count(*) as duplicate
     from tableA t1

    where exists ( select 1 from tableB t2 where t2.B=t1.B
                                           and COALESCE(t2.B,t2.c) is not null
                 )
    group by t1.A
    having count(*)>1
```